# Maximum size of a clique

Tags: graph-theory

In doing a problem from Graph Theory by West. In one question it asks you to find the maximum sized clique in the graph.  I think it's 5 (using the top or bottom vertex). However in the solution manual it mentions that because the graph contains two points of degree 3 this is not possible. Is that correct? Can anyone explain why if so?

[image]

Comment: What is a clique?  Why do you think the maximum size is $5$?

Comment: A clique is a set of pairwise adjacent vertices in a graph. Of you look at the vertice at the top you'll see it's adjacent to 5 other vertices

Comment: @bbpy-newb Your definition of clique is correct.  But "pairwise adjacent" means any two vertices are adjacent to each other.  It doesn't mean all vertices are adjacent to the top (or bottom) one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clique of size five would have to include at least one of the vertices of degree three, simply because there are only six vertices in the graph. However, in a clique of size five, *each* vertex must have four neighbours within the clique. A vertex of degree three cannot fulfill this.

Comment: Ahh I did not completely understand the definition. Thanks so much